# Cannot establish connection on two-way comms like SSH on Phase 2 VIP attached to LAN IP using NAT 1:1

Tags: vpn, nat, port-forwarding, ipsec, pfsense

As the title say, I cannot establish connection on two-way comms like SSH on Phase 2 VIP attached to LAN IP using NAT 1:1.

Phase 1 and Phase 2 is UP.
Phase 2 Remote IP is 192.168.1.248 and Local IP is 172.16.250.10 (VIP)

I created a NAT 1:1 both on LAN interface and IPSec interface which says:
External IP 172.16.250.10 (VIP...)
Internal IP 192.192.168.1.253 (Actual pfSense IP)

[image: NAT 1:1 Mappings]

To test this out I am trying only SSH at the moment.
I created two rules on the Firewall, one for ICMP and one for SSH.

ICMP works fine - Not sure why.
Here is the rule and the Packet Capture respectivelly, of the ICMP and the SSH:

Rules:

[image: Rules]

Packet Capture of the ICMP - Blurred some info because I am not sure what is it for...:

[image: ICMP Packet Capture]

And here is a Packet Capture of a SSH attempt - Which is unsuccessful, with both a telnet test and SSH test itself on log:

[image: SSH Packet Capture]

As you can see, pfSense did not responded like when doing the ICMP.
This also happens even if I allow all rules on IPSEC and LAN, and also happens in other services like Zabbix ports. For clarification: Yes, SSH is enabled.

I want to also inform beforehand that I created a static route for IN → OUT (Which works fine.)

[image: Static Route]

I went here because I am really out of ideas and need some help.
Can someone give me some light on this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was to create a BINAT on one of the sides, in order to prevent conflict for networks with the same adresses ranges.